# Understanding linear regression

Tags: regression, machine-learning, self-study, linear-model

In class we've seen that $a$ (the weights) must satisfy $$X^T (y-Xa) =0$$

Here $X$ is a $(n\times d)$ matrix (so we have $n$ samples in $\mathbb R^d$)

let's denote the residuals $r = y-Xa$. In our class notes, it is written that

> The normal equations require the residuals to be orthogonal to each of the columns of $X$.

Why?

> Therefore, the solution of the linear regression is a projection of $y$ onto the subspace spanned by $v_1 , \ldots , v_d$ (the columns of $X$)

Can you please explain this?

Comment: Welcome to CV, deficiencyOn. Please have a look at the `[self-study]` tag, and add it to your question: [questions with `[self-study]` tags are treated differently here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). You can edit your question to add this tag by clicking the "edit" link at lower left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that the squared error loss you are trying to minimize is
$$
(y-Xa)^T (y-Xa) = y^Ty - 2a^TX^Ty + a^TX^TXa;
$$
if you take all the derivatives with respect to each element of $a$ and arrange them into a column vector, you get
$$
-2X^Ty + 2X^TXa.
$$
Then you set that equal to zero to get a necessary condition for the minimization of the sum of squares. These are the "normal equations," and it is the expression you wrote earlier:
$$
X^T (y-Xa) =0.
$$

When you solve for $a$ you get $\hat{a} = (X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty$, which makes the fitted values (your quote refers to these as "solutions")
$$
\hat{y} = X\hat{a} = X(X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty.
$$
The matrix $d \times d$ matrix $X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T$ is known as the *projection matrix*. For more information on why it is called that, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_(linear_algebra)).

Comment: Yeah, alright. so basically $X^T \cdot r = 0$. expanding it, we get: $$r_1 x_1 + \cdots + r_nx_n = 0$$

Comment: How can I infer orthogonality? Moreover, the notes says that for *every* $i,j$: $r_i \cdot x_j = 0$ (if I'm not mistaken)

Comment: the $\cdot$ is unnecessary to write. But yes, that's right. Orthogonality means that any column vector of $X$, say $x_3$ is orthgonal to $r$, meaning $x_3^Tr = x_3 \cdot r  = 0$. The equation you just wrote is writing all $d$ of those equations simultaneously.

Comment: but how can it be inferred from $X^Tr = 0$? it's probably some linear algebra property, right?

Comment: @deficiencyOn I proved it for you in my answer. It's from setting the derivatives of the loss function equal to $0$.